# Custom Page-Template doesn't recognize CSS-Variable defined in <head>

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to control colors on my site. The CSS-Variables are declared in a  Tag in the head-section to be able to use PHP-Variables. It works fine on the main page (`front-page.php`) but doesn't work on the `impressum-page.php`

Played around with the order of loading `bootstrap/style.css/wp_head()`. Styles.css does work on `impressum-page.php` but not the CSS-Variable.

```
<head>

    <?php 
        $main_color = get_field('main_color');
        $secondary_color = get_field('secondary_color');
        $background_color = get_field('background_color');  
    ?>
    <style>
    :root {
        --primary-color: <?php echo $main_color; ?>;
        --primary-color-background: <?php echo $secondary_color; ?>;
    }

    body {
        background-color: <?php echo $background_color; ?>;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: when you see on the page source, does `--primary-color: <?php echo $main_color; ?>;` shows a proper css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it... the data gets fetched by an Advanced Custom Fields function called get_field(). As a second argument, you have to enter the post ID from the source, otherwise it defaults to the active post.